# Pinterest fails to retrieve the image

Tags: html, image, apache, .htaccess, pinterest

I've been setting up Pinterest for a web site and it all works up to the point when you finish pinning an image. I always get **"Whoops Sorry we could not fetch the image"**

First I tried to directly assign the pin-it button to one of my images by setting the `media` parameter, which opened a pop-up with the description I provided. The image in the thumbnail area was displayed correctly as well, but Pin-It would result in the error message mentioned before.

Looking further into this issue I found 2 interesting sources on the Internet: [This blog article](http://www.plaincitylife.com/2013/08/why-pinterest-could-not-fetch-image.html) recommended checking the .htaccess file of the Apache in case Pinterest gets blocked in some way, which isn't the case for me. I'm not blocking anything.

[Another article](http://blog.kissmetrics.com/image-bias-of-pinterest/) gave some more useful information pointing out that the image has to be visible and exist with an `<img>` tag on the page (and fulfilling a couple of other criteria). Applying all those suggestions (e.g. image size of 400x500, visible, etc.) still wouldn't work. I went as far as just putting a plain image in the middle of my page and tried to Pin it, which still failed!

Then I tried a pin-it button with just the URL and let Pinterest fetch the images, which worked as flawless as the popup before up to the point when I finally finish the pin-it and it fails to retrieve the image...

Anybody got any suggestions what else I could try? I do run my Apache on port 88 instead of 80, but I couldn't find anything that this is related to the error. Anything else? If further information is required I can provide them.

Answer (score 1):

There is a minimum and maximum size for an image that Pinterest will allow. I also found in the olden days ie a couple years ago there were characters in the image name that Pinterest did not like. I think they fixed that issue, but make sure your image is not tiny and not 5000 pixels wide.

The image does not have to be in an img tag, you can specify which image gets pinned in structured meta data, thus making it possible to display on your website an image in one size and give Pinterest a completely different sized image. You can use the same technique with Facebook, Twitter, Google+ assuming you get your structured meta data correct, you may also have to be "approved" to use Rich Pins/Twitter Cards.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Pinterest works fine on the production server, where we're using **port 80**. So the usage of port 88 might indeed have caused the issue.

It is a different environment though, so other factors might play a role as well.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the exact same problem but found that it was actually due to formatting in of the image's source tag.

Mine referred to `../images/example.jpg`, which displayed perfectly, allowing you to get as far as it showing in the Pinterest dialogs, but as soon as I altered the source to simply `images/example.jpg`, removing the unnecessary `../` it began to work.

Comment: if it was ../ it wasn't unnecessary as it means one step up in directory tree. Only ./ could be removed.